# (undetailed) Panic while creating Android Virtual Device (AVD)

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, panic

Programming newbie, just getting started with all of this...
I have searched around, but I haven't found anything relevant to my problem

So here it is,
So I'm trying to build a simple hello world application for android, but I wanted to test run the AVD just to check things out.
But I get this problem: [image: Screenshot 1]
(it just shows "PANIC: Cannot create AVD", no further info)

I have tried creating virtual devices based on 4.2 and 2.3.3, but none of these start up.
I have sdk up and running, no problem.[image: Screenshot 2]
I also have all the files required (like the system images etc)
Eclipse 64-bit also runs fine (had some errors, but solved them using search)

Any help?
I run windows 7 64bit, 500gb hdd, 4gb ram, i3@2.4ghz
SDK, Java, Eclipse and all other tools are 64bit based.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If the emulator takes up too much time to load or getting lags then you should try this. Called as Intel Virtualization Technology with HAXM.

I know this is not the answer of your question but that might be helpful for you. :) It can greatly increase emulator speed.

You can check : **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437922/successfully-running-an-android-avd-manager-and-creating-new-emulator/25521874#25521874)**

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, make sure that the amount of RAM the AVD will have access to is 512MB or less. It doesn't matter how much RAM your computer has, this is a bug.

Comment: I did use 512mb, no luck though

Comment: Do you have multiple hard drives in your computer?

Comment: I just have one 500gb hdd, but partitioned into 3 parts

Comment: Okay, that might be part of the problem. I did a couple google searches about your problem, and everyone with the problem had multiple drives or partitions.

Comment: This link might help, especially the part about creating an environment. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19084

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you run the following from shell/command prompt? This should give you more information when the emulator is launching and should help diagnose the issue.

```
emulator -verbose -avd <name of emulator>
```

Comment: Um, I don't exactly know what you're referring to
I ran this in both adb and cmd, but I get is "emulator is not recognized as an internal command"

Comment: The Android SDK needs to be added to your path for this to work (or you need an environment variable added). See this article http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/developer/android-sdk-install-guide/ and jump down to the "Installing the Android SDK section"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I seemed to have solved my problem
What I did was copy the default .android folder (it was auto generated in D:.android) to C:\Users\Administrator
Although this just works for one launch
For every subsequent avd launch, I had to re-copy the folder and replace only the edited files

Thanks everyone for trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

You must establish (from security or from the advanced properties of your PC) the local variable ANDROID_SDK_HOME to your docs folder.