# Successfully Running an Android AVD Manager and creating new Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

So I am a beginner to Android development and decided I would start learning based on the Android site itself how to make android apps. I thought a good place to start would be making my first emulator and running a minimal hello world program.

Using the Android Guide:

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/managing-avds.html

It instructs how to make an emulator but the appearance of my AVD is radically different than the one they are using and I have encountered an error with it which I cannot find online literature to fix:

Specifically the process they give to make a new virtual device is hit "new" (in my case I am guessing that is the same thing as "create" since there is no "new "button on the most recent version of AVD manager)

And after that a form appears, I am supposed to fill up the form with relevant Virtual Device information and hit "ok" to create the device.

Except... after filling all the information I still cannot hit "ok". The button is greyed out, and I have done everything exactly as the android guide told me. What should I do to fix this? I have the form displayed below notice the greyed out ok button on the bottom right corner.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the field: "CPU/ABI: No System images installed for this target". To rectify, open up the Android SDK Manager and download/install a System Image.

For example, when I open the Android SDK Manager, I expand the Android 4.4.2 (API 19) and install the ARM EABI v7a System Image (and for giggles, I might install the Intel image as well).

Whilst there, make sure you have other bits you might need for development (but not necessarily for the emulator) like the SDK and I'd definitely recommend downloading the sources, samples, SDK Tools, SDK Platform-tools and SDK Build-Tools.

You can use a later API version if you like, but API 19 has been released into production at the time of writing.

After which, you can restart the AVD and you'll be able to select the a CPU and create the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should add all the "Android System Images" to your Android SDK Manager.
For that,

- Open your SDK Manager from Windows -> Android SDK Manager.
- Now expand each Android API versions then check Google and Intel X86 both system images and also check Intel HAXM Installer in the Extras.
- Download and install them.
- After successful install, the status changes to be as "Installed".

Try this also:

Now if your system have a Processor that have a feature called as Intel Virtualization Technology, then Intel X86 images will be huge benefit for you. because it supports  Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM).

To check that your processor support HAXM or not : [Click Here](http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology)

You need to manually install the Intel HAXM in your system. Follow these steps for that.

- First of all go to -  adt -> extras -> intel -> Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
- Make sure that Intel Virtualization is enabled from BIOS Settings.
- Now install Intel HAXM in your system and select amount of memory(i prefer to set it as default value).
- After installation create new AVD which should have a Target of API Level xx
- Now set the CPU/ABI as Intel Atom(x86).
- If you are on Windows then do not set RAM value more than 768 MB while setting up an emulator.
- Run the emulator. It will be blazing fast then ordinary one.

Hope it will be helpful for you. :)